# RSpec not able to find class inside modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a class in app/services/a/b/c.rb

Rspec file is in spec/services/a/b/c_spec.rb

My class looks like this:

```
module a
 module b
   class c
   end 
 end
end
```

My rspec looks like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe a::b::c do
  describe '#test' do
    it 'should test func' do
    end
  end
end
```

But everytime I run the test I get this error::

> uninitialized constant a::b::c

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried restarting spring? I've found the app/services directory to not reload on change properly. You have to manually tell Spring to watch for changes in that directory via Spring.watch

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a problem with the code, assuming it's all as you've said.  I've tested it myself and it works OK.

Comment: per `app/services/A/B/C.rb` and `spec/services/A/B/C_spec.rb`, are the directory/files names in caps? If they are in caps then you are not following conventions. Make all dir/file names to small letters and try.

Comment: @AmitPatel classes are in small caps as per convention.

Comment: @elliotcm Somehow rails is not able to load the class in testing environment. In development it is working fine.

Comment: @Abhishek When I did my test I did it in the test env, so it must be some oddity with your setup.  Have you made any changes to `config/environments/test.rb` or elsewhere that might have altered or overwritten the autoload paths?

Answer (score 1):

@Abhishek I feel the problem is that your class isn't *required/loaded* by Rails.
Try requiring this file in spec_helper.rb.

Alternatively you can add that folder to eager_load_paths and set config.eager_load = true in config/environment/test.rb

You can confirm my hunch by using rails console in test environment and then check that invoking `A::B::C` gives `uninitialized constant A::B::C`.

Now try by requiring the `app/services/A/B/C.rb` file and this time it won't give the error.

Comment: Classes under app folder are automatically added in eager_load and autoload path. Classes are working fine in development env but in testing env rails is not able to load this class.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exact same issue, and the fix was pretty simple. I forgot to put:

```
require "rails_helper"
```

in the test file. After adding the `require` statement, it correctly loaded the class. (I'm aware that the questioner correctly added the require statement). May this answer help others.

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone else has this issue; I ended up fixing it by restarting my laptop.

For some reason, it wasn't finding classes nested inside of modules, but the restart fixed it. Wasted 2 hours on that.